# Extract based on instances of nodes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract some text using Beautiful Soup. The relevant portion looks something like this.

```
...
<p class="consistent"><strong>RecurringText</strong></p>
<p class="consistent">Text1</p>
<p class="consistent">Text2</p>
<p class="consistent">Text3</p>
<p class="consistent"><strong>VariableText</strong></p>
...
```

RecurringText, as the name implies, is consistent in all the files. However, VariableText changes. The only thing it has in common is it is the next  coded section. I'd like to get Text1, Text2, and Text3 extract. What comes before (up to and including RecurringText) and what comes after (including and after VariableText) can be left behind. The portion of extract from RecurringText I have found elsewhere, but I am unsure how to remove the next  item, if that makes sense.

In sum, how I can extract based on the characteristic of VariableText (which the string is variable throughout the urls) consistently coming after the last item of Text1, Text2, ..., Textn (where n is different across files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can basically get items from `p` element containing `strong` element to another `p` element containing `strong` element:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <p class="consistent"><strong>RecurringText</strong></p>
    <p class="consistent">Text1</p>
    <p class="consistent">Text2</p>
    <p class="consistent">Text3</p>
    <p class="consistent"><strong>VariableText</strong></p>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
for p in soup.find_all(lambda elm: elm and elm.name == "p" and elm.text == "RecurringText" and \
                       "consistent" in elm.get("class") and elm.strong):
    for item in p.find_next_siblings("p"):
        if item.strong:
            break
        print(item.text)
```

Prints:

```
Text1
Text2
Text3
```

Comment: Thanks! From my understanding, this looks for elements with the p class "consistent" that are strong, then goes to the next element that also matches that criteria. The problem is that there are multiple lists which look like this, but the list I am concerned with uniquely has RecurringText as its start. To modify your code, would it be best, after the initial search (to capture all of that general criteria), to find "RecurringText" and then go to the next sibling?

Comment: Thanks again! This is my first experience with Python/Beautiful Soup. Am I looking to read "Find all with lambda function" to learn more?

Comment: I ran into one error. It's actually `<p class="class1 class2">`. It seems the space causes problems. I looked this up and tried using `"class1.class2" in elm.get("class")`, but it seems that's not the right solution.